# conditional form

Tags: conditional-perfect

Here is what an English native said:

> If he felt this seven years ago, we would not have had a problem.

I think the correct version should be:

> If he **had** felt this seven years ago, we would not have had a problem.

Is there a difference in meaning between the two?

**Later edit**, here is the source:
http://www.nytimes.com/2003/12/14/business/who-s-afraid-of-eliot-spitzer.html

The context is this:

> Donald Simon, one of the three independent trustees who resigned from Mr. Navellier's board, said: ''I would find it amusing if he is leading the charge in governance when seven years ago it was a different attitude. Maybe he has learned this is the way to go. If he felt this seven years ago, we would not have had a problem.''

Comment: Yes, the "had" is required there.  It's possible, though, that the speaker said **If he'd felt this..."** quickly enough that the *d* was hard to distinguish.

Comment: You're right. Ordinarily both clauses of a conditional have to lie on the same side of the *realis/irrealis* divide.

Comment: As I just said in a different comment on a different subject, if the result is the same either way, there's nothing to choose except presuppositions. The first one is somewhat less committal about his past feelings than the second one, but the point is the same in either case. Most people wouldn't think twice at hearing either version, so the simpler one is more likely to be emitted by default, whatever the beliefs of the speaker about the proper use of the past perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that *had* is technically required for proper grammar. This is the "past perfect" tense, while *I felt* is the "simple perfect". [What difference does using 'had' make to those two verb tenses, and if so, what is it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24948/what-difference-does-using-had-make-to-those-two-verb-tenses-and-if-so-what/24955#24955) describes the differences in general between them.

However, in this particular context, *had* serves little purpose. The qualifier *7 years ago* makes it clear when the supposed feeling would have taken place. In casual speech and writing, redundant auxiliaries like this are often elided, with no effect on the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three errors here:

*''I would find it amusing [**that**] he is leading **[now]** the charge in governance when seven years ago **he had** a different attitude. Maybe he has learned this is the way to go. **Had he felt this way** seven years ago, we would not have had a problem.''*

or, without that "would" that seems to trouble some:

*''**I find it amusing he is leading** **[now]** the charge in governance when seven years ago **he had** a different attitude.  Maybe he has learned this is the way to go. **Had he felt this way** seven years ago, we would not have had a problem.''*

or:

*''**I would find it** amusing **if he were leading** **[now]** the charge in governance when seven years ago **he had** a different attitude. **[But]** Maybe he has learned this is the way to go. **Had he felt this way** seven years ago, we would not have had a problem.''*

The OP is confusing on whether "he is leading or not," so I provided more alternatives.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with _amusing if_. And _he had_ would be more precise, but this was speech. In speech, "correcting" an _if_ clause to an inverted _Had he_ is just grotesque.

Comment: In fact, *I would find it amusing that* is noticeably worse than the original, since it leaves the conditional dangling.

Comment: @TimLymington  Cf.  New York - Volume 37, Issues 2-9 - Page 166
2004 ___I would find it amusing that__ I can't find the hostess (oh, she's there, pretty enough to be hovered around by a pack of dry-clean-jeaned, Fendi- monogram-loafered satyrs)_.

Comment: @ColinFine  Cf. "Had he" in speech:  Gilligan's Wake: A Novel - Page 263
Tom Carson - 2007 - ‎
_And finally, __he said, had he__ and his compatriots __been informed__ that afterward they'd need to prove day in day out and all the time that they'd been deserving, __they might well have waved__ the fleet off._

Comment: Marius : It is a curious delusion that one counterexample makes any locution acceptable. The internet is a big place, and bloggers, journalists, even (hush!) ELU contributors make mistakes. The language *can* change to accommodate them, but it takes a long time and a lot of examples.  (You also seem to have misunderstood what Colin meant by "in speech".)

Comment: @MariusHancu: Certainly, some people use the literary form "Had he ... " in speech sometimes: I'm sure I have done so myself on occasion. What I described as grotesque was telling a learner that "If he felt" was an error, and "Had he felt" was not.